# Cull all duplicates in a set

Tags: java, set, set-theory

I'm using Set to isolate the unique values of a List (in this case, I'm getting a set of points):

```
Set<PVector> pointSet = new LinkedHashSet<PVector>(listToCull);
```

This will return a set of unique points, but for every item in *listToCull*, I'd like to test the following: if there is a duplicate, cull all of the duplicate items.  In other words, I want pointSet to represent the set of items in *listToCull* which are already unique (every item in *pointSet* had no duplicate in *listToCull*).  Any ideas on how to implement?

EDIT - I think my first question needs more clarification. Below is some code which will execute what I'm asking for, but I'd like to know if there is a faster way.  Assuming listToCull is a list of PVectors with duplicates:

```
Set<PVector> pointSet = new LinkedHashSet<PVector>(listToCull);
    List<PVector> uniqueItemsInListToCull = new ArrayList<PVector>();
    for(PVector pt : pointSet){
        int counter=0;
        for(PVector ptCheck : listToCull){
            if(pt==ptCheck){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter<2){
            uniqueItemsInListToCull.add(pt);
        }
    }
```

uniqueItemsInListToCull will be different from pointSet.  I'd like to do this without loops if possible.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you are asking.  If you create a set from a list, it will produce the set of distinct items in the list.  What more are you asking for?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to put in the set only those items that are unique, or, equivalently, exclude from the set objects that are duplicated in the list. Am I right?

Comment: Barranka - Yes! That's what I'm setting out to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do some programming yourself: Create two empty sets; on will contain the unique elements, the other the duplicates. Then loop through the elements of `listToCull`. For each element, check whether it is in the duplicate set. If it is, ignore it. Otherwise, check if it is in the unique element set. If it is, remove it there and add to the duplicates set. Otherwise, add it to the unique elements set.

If your `PVector` class has a good `hashCode()` method, `HashSet`s are quite efficient, so the performance of this will not be too bad.

Untested:

```
Set<PVector> uniques = new HashSet<>();
Set<PVector> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
for (PVector p : listToCull) {
    if (!duplicates.contains(p)) {
        if (uniques.contains(p)) {
            uniques.remove(p);
            duplicates.add(p);
        }
        else {
            uniques.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may use a third-party library which offers a `Bag` or `MultiSet`. This allows you to count how many occurrences of each element are in the collection, and then at the end discard all elements where the count is different than 1.

Comment: Thanks Hoopje, I'll look into Bag and MultiSet.  I'm trying to do this in native Java (without loops) if possible.

Comment: I've since learned that this is the most efficient method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

#### What you are looking for is the `intersection`:

Assuming that `PVector` (*terrible name by the way*) implements `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly a `Set` will eliminate duplicates.

If you want a `intersection` of the `List` and an existing `Set` create a `Set` from the `List` then use [`Sets.intersection()` from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) to get the ones common to both sets.

```
public static <E> Sets.SetView<E> intersection(Set<E> set1, Set<?> set2)
```

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the intersection of two sets. The returned set contains all
>   elements that are contained by both backing sets. The iteration order
>   of the returned set matches that of set1. Results are undefined if
>   set1 and set2 are sets based on different equivalence relations (as
>   HashSet, TreeSet, and the keySet of an IdentityHashMap all are).
>
> Note: The returned view performs slightly better when set1 is the
>   smaller of the two sets. If you have reason to believe one of your
>   sets will generally be smaller than the other, pass it first.
>   Unfortunately, since this method sets the generic type of the returned
>   set based on the type of the first set passed, this could in rare
>   cases force you to make a cast, for example:
>
> Set aFewBadObjects = ...    Set manyBadStrings =
>   ...
>
> // impossible for a non-String to be in the intersection
>   SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    Set badStrings = (Set)
>   Sets.intersection(
>          aFewBadObjects, manyBadStrings); This is unfortunate, but should come up only very rarely.

You can also do `union`, `complement`, `difference` and `cartesianProduct` as well as `filter`ing very easily.

Comment: Thank you Jarrod, I believe this is moving in the right direction.  If I can get the Set from the original List, as well another list of all removed items, I can do a difference between the Set and removed items.  I'll look into a quick method for tracking down the removed items (without looping).

Answer (score 0):

So you want pointSet to hold the items in listToCull which have no duplicates?  Is that right?

I would be inclined to create a Map, then iterate twice over the list, the first time putting a value of zero in for each PVector, the second time adding one to the value for each PVector, so at the end you have a map with counts.  Now you're interested in the keys of the map for which the value is exactly equal to one.

It's not perfectly efficient - you're operating on list items more times than absolutely necessary - but it's quite clean and simple.

Comment: Thank you Carl, but I'm inclined to find a more efficient  method.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the solution I've come up with, I'm sure there are better ones out there but this one's working for me.  Thanks to all who gave direction!

To get unique items, you can run a Set, where listToCull is a list of [PVectors](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) with duplicates:

```
    List<PVector> culledList = new ArrayList<PVector>();
    Set<PVector> pointSet = new LinkedHashSet<PVector>(listToCull);
    culledList.addAll(pointSet);
```

To go further, suppose you want a list where you've removed all items in listToCull which have a duplicate.  You can iterate through the list and test whether it's in the set for each item.  This let's us do one loop, rather than a nested loop:

```
    Set<PVector> pointSet = new HashSet<PVector>(listToCull);
    Set<PVector> removalList = new HashSet<PVector>();//list to remove

    for (PVector pt : listToCull) {
        if (pointSet.contains(pt)) {
            removalList.add(pt);
        }
        else{
            pointSet.add(pt);
        }
    }
    pointSet.removeAll(removalList);
    List<PVector> onlyUniquePts = new ArrayList<PVector>();
    onlyUniquePts.addAll(pointSet);
```